# Visual C++ - Set the depth of template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Can I change the depth of template instantiation when compiling with the Visual Studio compiler?

I need an equivalent of gcc's

```
-ftemplate-depth = Num
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you really have templates that nest more than 17 (pre C++11) or 1024 (C++11 onwards) levels?

Comment: Just asking if it's tweakable

Comment: A small remark: Visual C++ [compiler limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx).

Comment: And another one: Visual C++ [compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx). Nothing about  templates.

Comment: You may try to change your (meta-?) program logic to keep within the compiler limits.

Comment: Things work a little different if your customers have to pay for the product.  If your compiler runs out of stack compiling code then they'll make it *your* problem.  Any kind of "turn on this option to prevent the compiler from crashing" answer is a non-starter, it has to be a diagnostic.

Comment: fwiw, in the [Boost.Variant documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html), there is a section on how to combat gcc and MSVC compiler errors. Where they recommend to increase `-ftemplate-depth` for gcc, they suggest to use `/ZmNNN` with `NNN` a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is fixed at 2048. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft39hh4x.aspx.

Comment: How can you tell that template recursion is fixed at 2048 ? It's the template parameter count which is fixed at 2046?