# How to allow higher template recursion limit in MSVC?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, template-meta-programming, lookup-tables

I'm writing template metaprogramming code in C++ to generate a look-up table for embedded programming purposes (lack of FPU). I've been using MSVC for prototyping.

When trying to generate the final 128x128, 2 bytes per cell LUT, I'm getting error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex.

But for 100x100, it gets generated in seconds and all is well. I haven't been able to find how to increase the template recursion limit in MSVC on the web.

According to this question from 2014 asking the same thing, [Visual C++ - Set the depth of template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23375567/visual-c-set-the-depth-of-template-instantiation), there was none, but I hope things have changed since and someone here may know about it.

Here is the code for context:

```
const size_t tableSize = 128;
const float unit = 80.;
using Cell = std::pair<uint8_t, uint8_t>;

constexpr auto f = [](uint8_t x, uint8_t y) -> Cell {
    float _x = x / unit;
    float _y = y / unit;

    float norm2 = std::sqrt(_x * _x + _y * _y);
    float norm2Min1 = norm2 < 1 ? 1 : norm2;
    return {(uint8_t)(x / norm2Min1), (uint8_t)(y / norm2Min1) };
};

template<uint8_t rowNo, uint8_t columnNo> struct Row {
    Cell cell = f(columnNo, rowNo);
    Row<rowNo, columnNo + 1> rest;
};
template<int rowNo> struct Row<rowNo, tableSize-1> {
    Cell cell = f(tableSize-1, rowNo);
};

template<int rowNo> struct Table {
    Row<rowNo, 0> row;
    Table<rowNo + 1> rest;
};
template<> struct Table<tableSize-1> {
    Row<tableSize-1, 0> row;
};

struct LUT {
    Table<0> table;

    Cell precomputedF(uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {
        return ((Cell*)(&table))[y * tableSize + x];
    }
};

int main()
{
    LUT lut;
    int size = sizeof(LUT);

    std::cout << size << "\n\n";

    for (int x = 0; x < tableSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < tableSize; y++) {
            auto result = lut.precomputedF(x, y);
            std::cout << "(" << (int)result.first << "," << (int)result.second << ")" << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack on Windows is usually pretty lean, which means you'll need to be careful about chewing up stack space with large arrays, or tons of small ones. Can you **please show code for context**?

Comment: Hey @tadman, just added the code.

Comment: My mistake, the leading ``` of code formatting ate my first line visually. Also one way to cut space here is to switch to a triangular LUT because normalization of a x,y vector is symmetric. But I was hoping for a general solution.

Comment: I would try ditching the recursion in the first place and use constexpr/conteval functions to generate the LUT instead.  Then you can use for loops instead of recursion.

Comment: Why are you using recursive templates for this, and not `constexpr`?

Comment: That would be simpler, fair point...

Comment: Yes you can just fill a std::array<std::array<float,128>,128> directly from loops.

Comment: An alternative that I've used was to write a program that did all the heavy lifting calculations and output the results as C code — as a pre-calculated data array — that I could `#include` in my C code.  (It's been a while.  Before I learned C++, so 1980s.)

Comment: BTW, `precomputedF` invokes UB, you do pointer arithmetic on non-array.

Comment: *"How to allow higher template recursion limit in MSVC?"* One workaround (for general case) is to instantiate explicitly some intermediate instance.

Comment: @Jarod42 Pointer arithmetic is UB even to move within one struct whose structure is known ?!?

Comment: Even re-implementing vector would be pedantically UB for user. In the same way `struct Vec3{ int x, y, z; int& operator[](int i) {return &x + i;} };` is UB (for `i != 0`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use templates. Use `constexpr`

```
using Table = std::array<std::array<Cell, tableSize>, tableSize>;
consteval Table make_LUT() {
    Table table;
    for(size_t x=0; x<tableSize; x++) {
        for(size_t y=0; y<tableSize; y++)
            table[y][x] = f(x,y);
    }
    return table;
};
constexpr Table LUT = make_LUT();
constexpr Cell precomputedF(uint8_t x, uint8_t y) {
    return LUT[y][x];
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d406313f9bec451

---

If you really want to stick with something closer to your original code, you can simply use `std::make_integer_sequence<uint8_t,tableSize>()` to eliminate the recursion in the templates. This has a max depth of 2, instead of 2xtableSize.  I haven't quite worked out the syntax to create the table with a max depth of 1 yet, but I suspect it's possible.

```
template<uint8_t row, std::uint8_t... columns>
constexpr TableRow makeTableRow(std::integer_sequence<uint8_t,columns...>) {
  TableRow t = {{f(columns,row)...}};
  return t;
};
template<std::uint8_t tableSize, std::uint8_t... rows>
constexpr Table makeTable(std::integer_sequence<uint8_t,rows...>) {
  Table t = {{makeTableRow<rows>(std::make_integer_sequence<uint8_t,tableSize>())...}};
  return t;
};
constexpr Table lut = makeTable<tableSize>(std::make_integer_sequence<uint8_t,tableSize>());
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345718b3818c2231

Comment: Thanks! By the way, to anyone finding this answer, make sure you're using C++20 to get constexpr std::pair.

Comment: And use `consteval`, rather than `constexpr`